# How can I optimize an Electron JS application size?

Tags: reactjs, optimization, electron, electron-builder, electron-react

I've made a simple desktop app, using React, (with Vite), and Electron JS. I've checked the bundle size of the final files of only the React app, (the CSS, js and html), and it's as expected very very low.

Then I used Electron builder to do the packaging, selected to do it portable for Windows, but the size of the resulting application is crazy big compared to what the React bundle size is, it's 168MB, I don't know what to do to make it less. I've been searching on Electron and Electron builder documentation but I haven't gotten an answer, can anyone help me?

I tried optimizing the React app performance, which I did, yet nothing changes the size of the final executable made by Electron builder

**package.json config:**

```json
{
  "name": "venedolar-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Monitor application that displays the currencies of Venezuela up to date",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/electron.cjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "author": "Gabriel Trujillo",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.3.2",
    "electron": "^27.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.4",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.venedolar.app",
    "productName": "Venedolar",
    "copyright": "Copyright @ 2023 Gabriel Trujillo, Diego Peña",
    "win": {
      "icon": "dist/icon2.ico",
      "target": [
        "portable"
      ],
      "artifactName": "Venedolar1.0_portable.exe"
    },
    "directories": {
      "output": "build",
      "buildResources": "dist"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your electron builder config.

Comment: `"build": {
    "appId": "com.venedolar.app",
    "productName": "Venedolar",
    "copyright": "Copyright @ 2023 Gabriel Trujillo, Diego Peña",
    "win": {
      "icon": "dist/icon2.ico",
      "target": [
        "portable"
      ],
      "artifactName": "Venedolar1.0_portable.exe"
    },
    "directories": {
      "output": "build",
      "buildResources": "dist"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "public/electron.cjs",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ]
  }`

Here it is

Comment: I will do it for you but when you add additional information you should edit your question and not write it as comment. Thank you

Comment: oh thanks, sorry i'm new here

Comment: No problem, don't worry. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A packaged app will always be bigger than your source code because it includes Electron binaries, which are about 150mb in size (for Windows). You can only optimize the size of the resource folder, which is the part of your code you package.

According to your config, you don't only pack your bundled files:

```json
"files": [
  "dist/**/*",
  "public/electron.cjs",
  "node_modules/**/*",
  "package.json"
]
```

When your files are bundled, you no longer need the `node_modules` folder, which will increase the size of your app. The ideal would be to have just that:

```json
"files": [
  "dist/**/*",
]
```

In your case, it means you should tell Vite to also bundle `electron.cjs`. I'm not familiar enough with this bundler, so I won't be able to give you a config for that.

Comment: Hi again, i've tried it, but still the same output, the result it's the artifact that has a size of 68mb, and inside the win_unpacked folder, an application that has a size of 168mb again, i added the whole package.json config already

Comment: @Gab 68mb for the .exe installer and 168mb for the app .exe sounds normal to me. Don't forget your app comes with chromium, it will not fit in 5mb. The min size is usually ~150mb, you can only optimize the size of the resource folder. I will edit my answer to include these information.

Comment: If the size didn't change when your removed `node_modules`, then maybe they where already removed somehow, you can check what's packaged by checking inside `app.asar` (you can temporarily disable `asar` in your config for that).

Comment: understood, thanks for the help, i tried thing and it came down to 1mb less lmao, but at least it's something, how do i check the app.asar?

Comment: @Gab if you disable `asar` you can see what's packaged: `asar: false` (but only do this to check, keep `asar` enabled for prod).

Comment: Okk, thanks for the help!